# Реализация выделение областей при наведении на backround

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

Ребят подскажите как сделать map не на картинке, а на backrounde.
Пример как сделано на картинке тут http://hello-site.ru/web-notes/videlenie-oblastei-maphilight/
Нужно тоже самое только выделить области, но на backrounde.
Почему backround -  я делаю его масштабирование при ресайзе экрана- соотвественно плагины типа  maphilight.js не подходят, там каждый раз нужно отрисовывать canvas по новой пр масштабировании

Comment: если коротко - никак :-)

Comment: скорее всего ты ошибаешся

Comment: почему ты так думаешь? :-)

Comment: http://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/example/

Comment: @soledar10, ну тут же тот же самый `map` :-) а в вопросе: background

Comment: А как вы вообще представляете: _наведение на background_?

Comment: не знаю, мне кажется все равно есть какое то решение

Comment: предлагаете вставить картинку и ресайзить ее

Comment: @ruslik, вообще как вариант - использовать svg картинку - и ей на элементы навесить hover. Она масштабируется автоматом. Иначе - только то что предложил soledar, или никак